# Can I Spawn the Ender Dragon even if I broke it on creative?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

So I broke the Ender Dragon egg on creative and I don't know if you can get it back? Can I bring it back? Or can I spawn a different portal but on the same world? 
-ps.: I'm on the PS3

Comment: Does PS3 have command blocks yet, if so just put this in there /give @p [item ID] if not then the only way is to kill the ender dragon again which is impossible as far as I know sorry...

Comment: You'll have to create a new world. Instead, use pistons to move it, that will let you pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

In the new edition you can ”generate a new end” from the edit world screen.